# How can I Make from Flutter Project files a one single file to install it on Android or IOS?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-test

I am just starting learn Flutter, I build a simple as you see on the photos.
My problem is I have a windows 11 and I don't have any MacOS Device, But I want to use my app on my iPhone, and I want to get a file so I can download the app and use it on my iPhone, and I would like to know the same thing for Android devices, I don't want to test the app on my android device I want to be able to install it.
so if anyone knows the solution help me.
[See my App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ic7AP.png)

Comment: You need to create separate installation files for Android and iOS. You need a Mac to build an app for an iOS device. You may be able to use a cloud build solution, like Code Magic. You cannot build it on Windows directly.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot create Apple based apps on Windows, however your can deploy your flutter-web app to firebase,for example, and use as web-app.
If you want to have apk file for android devices run this command on your terminal

`flutter builld apk --release --split-per-abi`

Comment: Thanks for your help I tried the command and it works, But for ios Can I do anything without having MacOS device?
or there is no chance of doing anything

Comment: As far as I am programming on Windows I could not deploy any ios apps, however you can design by using [Cupertino widgets](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/widgets/cupertino) on windows then release ios app with MacOs device.

Comment: okay If I want to put my app on a hosting server so I can use it from any device , what should I do? just putting the project files on the server?

Comment: when you deploy your web-app to a hosting server, you can access through any devices. There is a tutorial with this id v=9qmSrt-DLiA  how to deploy web-app.